# Subclass constructor without one parameter - is it possible? How to do that?

Tags: java, oop, subclass, superclass

Let's start with code first

This is my superclass

```
public class Burger {

protected String name;
protected MeatType meat;
protected BreadType bread;
private double basePrice;
private EnumMap<Addition, Integer> additions;

public Burger(String name, MeatType meat, BreadType bread){
    this.name = name;
    this.meat = meat;
    this.bread = bread;
    this.basePrice = 3.00;
    this.additions = new EnumMap<Addition, Integer>(Addition.class);
}
```

and this is the subclass inheriting from it

```
public class FitBurger extends Burger {

public FitBurger(String name, MeatType meat, BreadType bread){
    super(name,meat,bread);
    }

}
```

However, I don't want my subclass to have a constructor with the BreadType bread but still I want it to keep inherit the variable and set it to a particular value. I want the superclass to remain the way it is too.

Is it possible to achieve that in any possible way?

Comment: Just call `super(name, meat, BreadType.WHATEVER)`, and remove the parameter.

Comment: You have to call `super` with valid values for these three parameters.  How many parameters you have in sub-class constructor is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> but still I want it to keep inherit the variable and set it to a particular value. I want the superclass to remain the way it is too. Is it possible to achieve that in any possible way?

Yes. You can pass a constant to the `super()` call. Like,

```
public FitBurger(String name, MeatType meat){
    super(name,meat,RYE_BREAD_CONSTANT);
}
```

Comment: ahh of course! How could I forget about predefining the bread in the super() call as a constant. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the BreadType from the FitBurger constructor, but pass in a value in the super call.

```
public class FitBurger extends Burger {

    public FitBurger(String name, MeatType meat){
        super(name,meat,BreadType.Bun);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public FitBurger(String name, MeatType meat){
    super(name,meat,null);
}
```

Add this new constructor to your `FitBurger` class or replace the existing one .

Answer (score 0):

Omit the BreadType bread parameter from your subclass constructor, and use `super(name,meat, null)` or whatever you want to use as you default BreadType